# KnockoutJS computed observable within an observable

Tags: knockout.js, this, scope, self

I have a ViewModel containing the following observable:

```
self.obFoo = ko.observable({
    foo: ko.observable(""),
    bar: ko.observable("")
});
```

Now I want to add a new computed observable to obFoo that depends on both foo and bar, something like this:

```
self.obFoo = ko.observable({
    foo: ko.observable(""),
    bar: ko.observable(""),
    foobar: ko.computed(function(){
          return foo() + bar();
    })
});
```

The problem is that foo and bar are not defined within the scope of foobar. I tried adding 'this' or even 'self.obFoo' as a second parameter to the computed but neither worked.

Is there a way to get the right scope into the computed foobar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a proper constructor function for your object:

```
var MyObject = function(){
    this.foo = ko.observable("foo");
    this.bar = ko.observable("barr");
    this.foobar = ko.computed(function(){
          return this.foo() + this.bar();
    }, this);
}
```

And use the constructor function to create your object instead of the object literal:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.obFoo = ko.observable(new MyObject());
}
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LUK35/).

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. Just so I understand - wrapping it in a function gives you a local 'this' that is properly scoped?

Comment: wrapping to a function is not necessery enough. You need to pass in the `this` as the second argument of the computed to make sure that it will work.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do this:

```
var o={
    foo: ko.observable(""),
    bar: ko.observable("")

};
o.foobar= ko.computed(function(){
          return o.foo() + o.bar();
    });

self.obFoo = ko.observable(o);


self.obFoo().foobar();
```