# knockoutjs - computed observables inside observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have a ViewModel which is an observable array of  objects that hold contacts' information that i am going to output using `foreach`. I need to have a computed observables that are dependent on `firstName` and `lastName` of each contact:

```
var contacts = ko.observableArray([
    {
        firstName: ko.observable("Jim"),
        lastName:  ko.observable("Carrey"),
        fullName:  ko.computed(function(){
            return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
        }, this),
        image:     ko.observable("images/jim.jpg"),
        phones:    ko.observableArray([
            {type: ko.observable("Mobile"), number: ko.observable("(555) 121-2121")},
            {type: ko.observable("Home"), number: ko.observable("(555) 123-4567")}
        ])
    },
    ...//other objects of the same structure
]);
ko.applyBindings(contacts);
```

but i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'firstName'`. Can someone explain why my reference to this.firstName() fails? Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arrustamyan/kD83g/

Comment: any reason using computed function inside obs array?

Comment: i am building an application where first and last names are editable, so they must update UI to reflect changes

Comment: i am also not expert with knockout. But can you remove computed function inside your obs array and have seperate computed function. I have created fiddle but somehow getting error. if you can fix then should work for you http://jsfiddle.net/kD83g/12/

Comment: May i request downvoter to add comment when downvoting questions.

Comment: the answer to this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21256964/knockoutjs-computed-observable-within-an-observable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `this` in your contact definitions doesn't refer to the contacts themselves; it refers to the global object. Use a function (either a "classical" constructor or simply a function that creates an object literal and returns it) to create the contacts so that it can set their context properly.

Comment: what i can't understand is why `this` is not pointing to the current object? is there a documentation i can read on this?

Comment: You might try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: the [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) says: "When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on.". Does it mean if i call ko.computed without the second parameter like this `fullName: ko.computed(function () {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }),` then `this` will refer to my contact object?